# Stock methods for unpacking concatenated values in dataframe cell?

Tags: python, pandas

Are there good existing methods for converting between these two forms?

```
+--------+-------------+
| FRUIT  | ATTRIBUTES  |
+--------+-------------+
| banana | long|yellow |
+--------+-------------+
| kiwi   | brown|oval  |
+--------+-------------+
```

and

```
+--------+-----------+
| FRUIT  | ATTRIBUTE |
+--------+-----------+
| banana | long      |
+--------+-----------+
| banana | yellow    |
+--------+-----------+
| kiwi   | brown     |
+--------+-----------+
| kiwi   | oval      |
+--------+-----------+
```

I'm currently iterating over rows for the unpacking process, and I've heard that's not encouraged.

```
import pandas as pd

packed = pd.DataFrame([['banana', 'long|yellow'], 
                       ['kiwi', 'brown|oval']], 
                      columns=['FRUIT', 'ATTRIBUTES'])

pack_delim = '|'

per_fruit_frames = []

for row in packed.itertuples(index=True, name='Pandas'):
    row_attribs = row.ATTRIBUTES
    row_attribs_split = row_attribs.split(pack_delim)
    row_attribs_series = pd.Series(row_attribs_split)
    ras_len = len(row_attribs_split)
    fruit_rep = [row[1]] * ras_len
    frs = pd.Series(fruit_rep)
    temp = pd.concat([frs, row_attribs_series], axis=1)
    per_fruit_frames.append(temp)
    
unpacked = pd.concat(per_fruit_frames)

unpacked.columns = packed.columns
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
packed=(packed.assign(ATTRIBUTES=packed['ATTRIBUTES'].str.split('|'))
              .explode('ATTRIBUTES',ignore_index=True))
```

OR

In 2 steps:

```
packed['ATTRIBUTES']=packed['ATTRIBUTES'].str.split('|')
packed=packed.explode('ATTRIBUTES',ignore_index=True)
```

output of `packed`:

```
    FRUIT   ATTRIBUTES
0   banana  long
1   banana  yellow
2   kiwi    brown
3   kiwi    oval
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
>>> pd.merge(packed['FRUIT'], packed['ATTRIBUTES'].str.split('|').explode(),
             left_index=True, right_index=True)

    FRUIT ATTRIBUTES
0  banana       long
0  banana     yellow
1    kiwi      brown
1    kiwi       oval
```